# Analog to waitable timers in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, timer, synchronization

In unmanaged Win32 world I am used to waitable timers created with the [CreateWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API that can be used for synchronization calls such as [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and mainly for [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There must be an analog to waitable timers in .NET and C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you need the waitable timer for?

The default class for 'something I can wait for' in .NET is [`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.100).aspx). In .NET 4.5, you can simply use [`Task.Delay(milliseconds)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx).

In .NET 4.0, you can use a [`TaskCompletionSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a task, and set it as completed using a normal timer. Or use the `TaskEx.Delay` implementation from the [Async Targeting Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29576) or [AsyncBridge](http://omermor.github.io/AsyncBridge/)

If you need an actual [`WaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle(v=vs.110).aspx), you could use a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx), and use a normal .NET timer to set the event.

Alternatively, you chould create your own class derived from `WaitHandle` and P/Invoke [`CreateWaitableTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682492(v=vs.85).aspx).
It seems that such a class already exists in the .NET framework, but it is internal. ([`System.Runtime.IOThreadTimer.WaitableTimer`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel.Internals/System/Runtime/IOThreadTimer.cs#601) from `System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll`)

```
public class WaitableTimer : WaitHandle
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern SafeWaitHandle CreateWaitableTimer(IntPtr lpTimerAttributes, bool bManualReset, string lpTimerName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetWaitableTimer(SafeWaitHandle hTimer, [In] ref long pDueTime, int lPeriod, IntPtr pfnCompletionRoutine, IntPtr lpArgToCompletionRoutine, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fResume);

    public WaitableTimer(bool manualReset = true, string timerName = null)
    {
        this.SafeWaitHandle = CreateWaitableTimer(IntPtr.Zero, manualReset, timerName);
    }

    public void Set(long dueTime)
    {
        if (!SetWaitableTimer(this.SafeWaitHandle, ref dueTime, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need it to include in a waiting function (that will wait for multiple objects: events and one of them is a timer.) I understand that I can do this with a callback function but that would require a redesign of my code. So, yeah, it seems like I'll have to go with Win32 API and P/Invoke. I'm just not very good at doing this P/Invoke stuff... Here's the link I found: http://www.anotherchris.net/csharp/wake-up-from-sleep-createwaitabletimer-in-csharp/

Comment: That link looks good to me; except that I'd use a custom `WaitHandle`-derived class instead of `EventWaitHandle`. The code in the link ends up creating an unused `AutoResetEvent`.

Comment: Thanks. One issue that I experienced is that if I create a repeating timer (or when the 3rd parameter of `SetWaitableTimer` is not 0), calling the first `wh.WaitOne()` works, but if I call it again, it doesn't wait for the timer's period. Any idea why?

Comment: The `dueTime` is actually [100ns intervals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686289(v=vs.85).aspx), or [ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: "What do you need the waitable timer for?" Answers could include the ability to wake up at an absolute time (not relative), including accounting for changes to the system clock, and resuming the computer from a suspended state if needed when the timeout occurs.